# android: Tracking install from Google Play

Tags: android

I have been trying to know if an app got installed when a user clicks a link in my app that redirects them to the play store. I am not using any of Google's ad campaigns or tools.

Basically, in my Activity, upon click,

```
Intent inte = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                "market://details?id=com.example.example&referrer=utm_source%3Dmy_referrer"));
        startActivity(inte);
```

I have a broadcast receiver, in the manifest in the application tags:

```
 <!-- Install Referrer -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.ex.ex.ReferrerReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Broadcast Receiver code:

```
package com.ex.ex;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class ReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "my_package";

    private String referrer = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Install received");

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
           if(extras != null){
              referrer = extras.getString("referrer");

           }

           Log.w(TAG,"Referrer is: "+ referrer);

    }

}
```

However, this broadcast receiver is never triggered.

Isn't this how the install tracker is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this in my Activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mInstallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Your code
        // Package name is in intent.getData() or intent.getDataString()
        // intent.getDataString() == "package:com.some.packagename"
    }
};

private void registerReceiver() {
    IntentFilter installFilter = new IntentFilter();
    installFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    installFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    registerReceiver(mInstallReceiver, installFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    registerReceiver();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(mInstallReceiver);
}
```

Comment: Can't this intent filter be set in XML? I need this to be triggered even if the app was not running.

Comment: In the `<intent-filter>` tag place `<data android:scheme="package" />` and `<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />`.